# UIView in view controller lags when popped

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

When I am popping a view controller off of a navigation stack, a blue view in the popped navigation controller sort of delays in going off screen and trails behind the rest of the view controller as shown in the video: https://vid.me/GbBG

What is the reason for this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: It seems something is blocking your main thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try this, it will surely works.**

write below line in `viewDidLoad:` of viewController containing Blue view(in 2nd View Controller).

```
self.view.clipsToBounds = true;
```

Reason : The width of your blue view is more than the width of `viewController.view`. So just you need to clip the area outside the `viewController.view`

Answer (score 1):

Change the background image(the blue one)'s width to be view.frame.width.

It will be better.